# CSS3 transform: translateX equivalent for right

Tags: css, transform

I want to do this: `-webkit-transform: translateX(300px)` but from the right instead of having the origin on left.
I tried `-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%` and even `top right` and it didn't affect it.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the power of **CSS**:

```
 body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#page {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:2;
    right:0;
}
#left_drawer {
    background-color: #222222;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#toggle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
.open_drawer {
    -webkit-animation: open_drawer 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes open_drawer {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
    }
}
```

This will make it slide in from the right. **[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GUW4N/12/)**